# function RGBtoHSV in java (image processing)

Tags: java, image-processing, rgb

I use function "RGBtoHSV" in java and build the array of V value (in array ModeValue[]), then print vary Modevalue[]. But something was strange, i found that the V value that shown is more than 1. Inspite of the range of Value should be in [0...1]. Here is a part of my code.

```
public static float[] ModeValue = new float[17415];  

public static void ValueArray (Bitmap myBitmap,int minw, int maxw,int minh, int maxh) {
Rred = 0;
Ggreen = 0;
Bblue = 0;
int count = 0;

for (int i=minw;i<maxw;i++){
    for (int j=minh;j<maxh;j++){
        int pixel = myBitmap.getPixel(i,j);

        Rred += pixel >> 16 & 0xFF;
        Ggreen += pixel >> 8 & 0xFF;            
        Bblue += pixel & 0xFF;          
        Color.RGBToHSV(Rred,Ggreen,Bblue,hsvMode);
        //create V array
        ModeValue[count] = hsvMode[2];
        HueValueMode[count] =  hsvMode[0];
        //can create h at this
        count++;
    }
}
```

}

please provide me an information, i don't know how to fix it. 
very thank you :-)

Comment: are u sure about Color.RGBToHSV(Rred,Ggreen,Bblue,hsvMode);? As long as I know, java.awt.Color only knows RGBtoHSB. Or are U using another Color class?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. public static void RGBToHSV (int red, int green, int blue, float[] hsv) 
Added in API level 1
Convert RGB components to HSV. hsv[0] is Hue [0 .. 360) hsv[1] is Saturation [0...1] hsv[2] is Value [0...1]